# integrating apache tomcat and solr

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, nutch

I am trying to integrate apache tomcat (version 7)and solr (version 4) and i am getting this error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect,
trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1212) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442) at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082) at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: 

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:821) at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:618) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:949) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:984) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:597) at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:592) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ... 1 more 

Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect at 
java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method) at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source) at 
org.apache.solr.core.StandardDirectoryFactory.normalize(StandardDirectoryFactory.java:47) 
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:462) at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:745) ... 11 more ,code=500}
```

please help me fix it!

Comment: Make sure your data directory path is correct

Comment: either in `core.properties` or in `solrconfig.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Solrconfig.xml and there will be a tag called as data directory , so just try to hard code the required path , if it works , then you can conclude that it is the root cause of the issue .

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following java environment variable in tomcat startup configuration (in JAVA_OPTS for example).

```
-Dsolr.solr.home=<your solr.xml path>
```